# Сортировка по буквам

Tags: php, sql

Как сделать [такую же](http://bit.ly/GY8nW3) сортировку по буквам? Интересует все от sql запроса до вывода в цикле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

при выборке из базы сортируем по возрастанию(order by). дальше вывод, запоминаем первую букву первого элемента, сразу же выводим её в качестве заголовка. далее при выводе следующего элемента проверяем изменилась ли первая буква, если да делаем новый заголовок с новой буквой, если нет выводим элемент. и т.д.

**Код:**

```
$arr = array('Actona', 'Aricasa', 'ARTE Lamp', 'Apollo', 'Anli', 'BONTEMPI', 'BelVase', 'Beal. Real', 'Blonder Home', 'Casa Vera', 'ClassicFlame', 'Easyfurn', 'FMD', 'Fif', 'FENICE', 'Forma Ideale', 'Friedrich von der Kohlen', 'Flocmat', 'FRAMAR', 'Garantie Mobel', 'Gumexpo', 'Globo', 'Germania', 'GIMI', 'Honsel', 'Haku', 'Heinz Hofmann', 'IMV-Steinheim', 'INNOVATION', 'InterFlame', 'Komforta Mobel', 'KESPER', 'Myflair', 'Marquis', 'Martini spa', 'NATISA', 'Nikotex', 'O&amp;G', 'ODISO', 'Paroli', 'Pushe', 'PRISMEA', 'Polster Luxe', 'PICARD &amp; WIELPUTZ', 'Primavelle', 'Pinella', 'Rinos', 'Ravel', 'Solutions', 'Sobranie', 'SSW', 'Trio', 'Vental', 'ZELLER');

$letter='';
foreach($arr as $r){
    if($letter!=$r[0]){
    $letter=$r[0];          
    echo '<h1>',strtoupper($letter),'</h1>';
    }
    echo '<br />название:', $r;
}
```

**upd**

```
$letter='';
foreach($arr as $r){
    if($letter!=$r['name'][0]){
    $letter=$r['name'][0];          
    echo '<h1>',strtoupper($letter),'</h1>';
    }
    echo '<br />название:', $r['name'],' id=',$r['id'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,но попробовал подстроить под себя не справился, потому что так же хочу вывести id для ссылок, есть массив такого вида
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Actona
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => BelVase
        )
)
как его пристроить к вашему коду? мучался, ниче не получилось

Comment: @dogmar изменил.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('Actona', 'Aricasa', 'ARTE Lamp', 'Apollo', 'Anli', 'BONTEMPI', 'BelVase', 'Beal. Real', 'Blonder Home', 'Casa Vera', 'ClassicFlame', 'Easyfurn', 'FMD', 'Fif', 'FENICE', 'Forma Ideale', 'Friedrich von der Kohlen', 'Flocmat', 'FRAMAR', 'Garantie Mobel', 'Gumexpo', 'Globo', 'Germania', 'GIMI', 'Honsel', 'Haku', 'Heinz Hofmann', 'IMV-Steinheim', 'INNOVATION', 'InterFlame', 'Komforta Mobel', 'KESPER', 'Myflair', 'Marquis', 'Martini spa', 'NATISA', 'Nikotex', 'O&amp;G', 'ODISO', 'Paroli', 'Pushe', 'PRISMEA', 'Polster Luxe', 'PICARD &amp; WIELPUTZ', 'Primavelle', 'Pinella', 'Rinos', 'Ravel', 'Solutions', 'Sobranie', 'SSW', 'Trio', 'Vental', 'ZELLER');
foreach(range('a', 'z') as $v) {
  $ar = array();
  foreach($arr as $val) {
    $s = strtolower($val);
    if ( $v == $s[0] ) {
      $ar[] = $val;
    }
  }
  if ( !empty($ar) ) {
    echo '<h1>' . strtoupper($v) . '</h1>' . implode('<br />', $ar);
  }
}
```

Comment: хех =) смешно.

Comment: Я не прошу вас о готовом примере, мне и сама логика процесса всего подойдет.

Comment: @dogmar, сорри, комент прочел после того как сделал.

Comment: а как же такие бренды как 21 Век, Золушка, -=мегакруть=-?

Comment: @FLK у меня бренды с русскими символами тоже присутствуют:)

Comment: @FLK, в вопросе это не указано.

Русские не сделал - этих хватит.